# Resolving Conflicts in Core Data with iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, synchronization, icloud

I'm writing an app that uses Core Data and is synced with iCloud. To do this, I have a UIManagedDocument that I set up as shown below:

```
UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:[self iCloudStoreURL]];
        document.persistentStoreOptions = @{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: [document.fileURL lastPathComponent], NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey: [self iCloudCoreDataLogFilesURL], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES};
        self.mydoc = document;
        [document release];

        [document.managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(documentContentsChanged:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:document.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(documentStateChanged:) name:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification object:document];


        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.mydoc.fileURL path]]) {
            // does not exist on disk, so create it
            [self.mydoc saveToURL:self.mydoc.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                [self populateTable];//synchronous call. few items are added
                [self iCloudIsReady];
            }];
        } else if (self.mydoc.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
            // exists on disk, but we need to open it
            [self.mydoc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                [self iCloudIsReady];
            }];
        } else if (self.mydoc.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
            // already open and ready to use
        }
    }
```

My issue with this approach is that I keep getting "Optimistic locking failure" when running the app in two devices. I read in Apple's Core Data documentation that a way to "avoid" this kind of issue was to set up the merge policy to NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy, something that I am already doing but for some reason is not working.

One thing I can't find is how to fix this. For example, if this is something that could happen, my app should be at least aware and prepared to handle this behavior. But I have no idea on how to handle this. For example, how do I get the conflicting objects and resolve them? Because every time this failure happens, I start getting UIDocumentStateSavingError when trying to save the document and the only way to stop getting this error is by killing the app and re-launching it.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Are you seeing corruption of your data or some other bad behavior?

Comment: This is a problem for two reasons. One, the data between the two devices becomes different. Two, the device that receives the failure can't save the document until you close the app.

Comment: I haven't used `UIManagedDocument` much but it has two nested managed object contexts, and its `managedObjectContext` only gets the child context. Maybe you need to set this on the parent context?

Comment: How does closing the app resolve the failure? That sounds like your managed object context is stale, meaning you haven't properly responded to the import notification.

Comment: I guess that by closing the app the managed object discards any object that triggered this failure. Exactly, as I said in the question, I don't know how to handle this issue. If there is a notification for this kind of failure, I don't know which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out (at least, I think I did). Apparently, on iOS6+ (I have no idea about iOS5) UIManagedDocument takes care of all the merging for you. So, the observer below, which was only responsible for calling "mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:" was in fact merging what was just merged.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(documentContentsChanged:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:document.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];

...

- (void)documentContentsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
      [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

Calling "mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:" was the line responsible for triggering the "Optimistic locking failure". I removed it and everything started working as expected. Unfortunately this only lasted a couple of hours. Now I keep getting the "iCloud Timed Out" error, but this one I'm sure it's Apple's fault.

Anyway, after a ton of bugs and three different iCloud + Core Data approaches, I think I will hold on integrating iCloud into my app. It is far too unstable and buggy. I really wish Apple could have fixed this with iOS6, iCloud + Core Data is a very powerful tool, unfortunately, it is not ready yet.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.